# JS on site behaves differently; browsers, os are same

Tags: javascript

We are debugging a site; these are the conditions:

Both devs are on same OS, same version (Windows 10)
Both devs are using same browser, same version (Chrome)

Since our dev boxes where built out identically (corporate america), there are no differences in other elements. JS version, so on.

I visit the site, JS fires differently than when co-worker visits.

What is going on? Are the End Times coming?

Comment: There are multiple reasons that could impact the seeming "randomness" of your application. Without any pieces of your code, we can't help you.

Comment: It would've helped if you provided the code and explained the expected behavior vs actual behavior.

Comment: They might have been built the same but are there any ways to confirm that they have both stayed the same? Just a guess: maybe one kept the browser up to date with the latest versions and the other didn't.

Comment: It may be because of the differences in system preference

Comment: Make sure you both have the latest version; i.e. not "cached"

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/intro.html) It may be helpful

### Browser incompatibilities

When a user receives a page which includes JavaScript, the JavaScript interpreter of his browser kicks in and tries to execute the script. Now the main problem here is that the various browsers each use their own interpreter, and that sometimes browser vendors have chosen not to implement a bit of JavaScript. Their reasons were usually related to business advantage over the competitors.

```
Hence the feared browser incompatibilities.
```

In addition each new browser version understands more JavaScript and allows more and more parts of the HTML page to be changed by scripts. This leads to even more incompatibilities.

Comment: *Both devs are using same browser, same version (Chrome)*. It's the same JavaScript engine and the same APIs are available.